# How I can get the value of grouping column inside user define function in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to start using data.table instead of dplyr as I have to speed up my calculations. 
Now my code for each element of the group uses the value of grouping column. 
However data.table drops it. For example

```
g <- function(x) {
   browser()
}

DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)

DT[,list(a = g(.SD)), keyby="x"]
```

Gives this when the value of `x` is queried from the browser:

```
   y v
1: 1 1
2: 3 2
3: 6 3
```

for first element of the group.

Is there any way how I can get value of x for each group in g()?

**UPDATE:**
I'm using a function where formula depends on the group, i.g.

```
g <- function(data) {
   if (x == "a") {
       return(y-v)
   } else {
       return(v-y)
   }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that what is being asked is how to refer to the grouping variable within a "j"-expression in `[.data.table`, but the function that is being used is not communicating a specific purpose for this request.

Comment: Thanks @BondedDust for the edit. kismsu, it's very much possible to get the grouping variable as well. Still, it'd help if you show what your actual task is so as to get a better idea (before to write an answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, assuming that this is more or less your function (meaning: it's short and/or similar), I'd do this directly in `j` like so:

```
DT[, .(a = (y-v) * (2L*(x=="a") - 1L)), by="x"]
# or if it's too cryptic
DT[, .(a = if (x=="a") y-v else v-y), by="x"]
```

Now assuming that your function is more complex, there are at least two other ways to go about this.

- First, by default values from grouping columns are of length-1. So, you could write a function that takes an additional argument which is the group value as follows:

  ```
  foo <- function(dt, grp) {
      if (grp == "a") dt[, y-v]
      else dt[, v-y]
  }
  DT[, .(a = foo(.SD, x)), by="x"]
  ```

  Here `grp` will be of length-1 (as explained above).
- Use `.SDcols` to add the grouping columns in `.SD` as well.

  ```
  foo <- function(dt) {
      if (dt$x[1L] == "a") dt[, y-v]
      else dt[, v-y]
  }
  DT[, .(a = foo(.SD)), by="x", .SDcols = c("x", "y", "v")]
  ```

  Although I'd prefer the first approach as it doesn't involve unnecessarily creating an extra column which has only one unique value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've found also that I can send .BY to function with a list of grouping values.